# What is the meaning of red stripe next to RDS instance name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

In AWS RDS web console, what is the meaning of red stripe next to RDS instance name (read replica pair)?

[image]

Also, in 'Replication' tab, both on replica master and slave, Read Master instance name is displayed in red color, but I don't see any errors anywhere, and replication seems to be working (replica lag 0ms, nothing in the error logs).

[image]

Thanks,
Dusan

Comment: I would contact AWS support to clarify it.

Comment: There's a surprising lack of documentation on this point.  Anecdotally, I see two orange bars next to one pair of instances (master and replica) and in another case, using cross-region replication, I have a purple bar next to the master and the same thing next to the replica... so it's almost as if it's some kind of "replication group identifier" ... but I have found nothing to confirm that, yet.

Comment: Strange. I have a green pair on another account. AWS forums are also still without any answer. It could be just a random color identifier, but you can imagine what it looks like to someone with one green pair, and another red pair :).

Comment: I would assume it is visual identifier to visually group clusters together (masters,replicas)

Comment: IIRC, it lets you know if CPU/RAM/disk usage are above a certain level.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [Tag](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_Tagging.html).

You can use Amazon RDS tags to add metadata to your Amazon RDS resources. In addition, these tags can be used with IAM policies to manage access to Amazon RDS resources and to control what actions can be applied to the Amazon RDS resources. Finally, these tags can be used to track costs by grouping expenses for similarly tagged resources.

To check your tags:

1. Sign in to the AWS Management Console and open the Amazon RDS console.
2. In the navigation pane, click Instances.
3. Click the details icon.
4. In the details pane, scroll down to **Tags**.